# Bind Kendo grid to CSV text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm using Telerik UI for ASP.Net MVC and I want to know how can I convert my model to CSV text and bind it to Kendo grid it will be more light than JSON while transfer data to the client.

Comment: The overhead of converting everything to CSV and parsing it in the browser won't pose a significant benefit over using the existing infrastructure and send everything with JSON. Do you have facts and figures supporting that CSV will be better than JSON?

Comment: You are right it can be over-heading to implement CSV formatter and use it instead of JSON, but as I said the csv text is more light than json it can save more than 30% of the size because it only contain the actual data without any definition/annotation before values only the first row contains the table header unlike Json which contains an definition for each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your concern, and I was actually doing the same things on my projects, trying to optimize the extra bytes from the JSON sent back to the client.

Turning something like this:

```
{
    status: true,
    data: [
        { name: 'aaa', lastName: 'ln1', identifier: 124343 },
        { name: 'bbb', lastName: 'ln2', identifier: 887875 },
        { name: 'ccc', lastName: 'ln3', identifier: 445455 }
    ]
}
```

Into this:

```
{
    s: 1,
    d: [
        { n: 'aaa', l: 'ln1', i: 124343 },
        { n: 'bbb', l: 'ln2', i: 887875 },
        { n: 'ccc', l: 'ln3', i: 445455 }
    ]
}
```

I got a shameful 10% savings by tweaking the JSON message and adjusting my client code (translate: overhead).

After a few analysis of my HTTP traffic I realized that GZIP compression was supported by the browser, the request headers of any decent browser include **"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"** but somehow my server was totally ignoring this thing because there was no response header saying **"Content-Encoding: gzip"**.

You can verify this by checking the request and response headers, see picture.

[image: Verifying gzip encoding on Firebug]

So after I forced the server to encode the content with GZIP compression if the client supports it, the network savings dropped to 80% of size.

GZIP compression is:
- Fast on the server
- Easy on the client
- You can choose where to activate it or not (let's say use it on responses that you know that will return a big amount of items)
- Benefits from repetitive text contents (as it uses a dictionary approach)

So believe me, the don't worry about how the JSON looks, use GZIP. I had to revert all of my overhead code afterwards.

Comment: I'm trying now on web Log table which has 7000 Row without nulls actual size 2 MB in Json format after GZIP became 373 KB, what a great result!!!!! and the best thing is that GZIP stream can be used with any content and will be more efficient in text data.
Thanks for your advice ;)